# Mobile reacts to scrolling but won't sccroll

Tags: mobile, responsive-design, scroll, viewport

I am having a problem when scrolling my site on mobile. While in responsinator.com, the website scrolls just fine. When its used on an actual mobile touch screen the site will react as I can see by my jQuery scroll functions but won't actually scroll anywhere.

The domain the site is currently hosted is: www.45-records.co.uk

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe a but in your script. Look there https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/issues

Answer (score 0):

If it's the [skrollr plugin](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr), add

```
id="skrollr-body"
```

to the html element in your website.